# Using a noun as a transitive verb in the sense of "to turn into"

Tags: nouns, slang, pronouns, transitive-verbs

This bit of made up slang from a tweet made me wonder what the proper grammarist's name is for the type of off-the-cuff concoction. What is meant here is "to turn into a Gollum type person" assuming the reader is aware of what kind of personality the character from a famous book and movie series (Lord of the Rings) is supposed to represent (needy, weak, manipulative, crafty, pathetic):

> child attachment is the most terrible attachment that exists. It
> should be a wonderful thing but god help you if your missus decides to
> go her own way. That'll gollum you right quick.

It's not uncommon; another computing slang example that comes to mind is "to brick" as in to turn a device inoperable.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brick#Verb

Answer (score 1):

It is called verbifying a noun.

[Verbify](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verbify) (Wiktionary): (transitive, nonstandard) To use a noun as a verb via anthimeria. (transitive, nonstandard, slang) To derive a verb from a pre-existing noun.

Comment: Great! Tried to upvote but am a pathetic n00b here so not allowed. Actually the term I was after is anthimeria which is contained there in the Wiktionary definition. The examples from Wikipedia are good, e.g.: "Me, dictionary-ing heavily, ... (Ernest Hemingway, Green Hills of Africa)" or "I'll unhair thy head. (Shakespeare, Antony and Cleopatra, II, v.)"

Comment: Thank you all the same. Glad that you found the answer useful.

Comment: Well, but that isn't a normal reading of using nouns as verbs. For instance consider the privative _skin a cat, milk a cow, seed a pepper_ versus the provisional _roof a house, fence a yard, seed a lawn_. Causatives are rare; I can't think of any offhand, and the example given seems odd.